# How does the browser really read if/else statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is a very simple question, but it might be realy useful for some of us. I've been looking for the answer in google, but I didn't find it. I have a doubt about how the browsers read the if/else statement. In short, When the condition is false, Does the browser just ignore the consequent (i.e. doesn't read it) or  the browser first read it but then it doesn't execute the code? The difference is huge when , e.g., you have a realy heavy long loop code. Thanks!

Comment: It is not the browser,  but the Javascript interpreter inside it, which parses the conditional statement of Javascript. And modern Javascript implementations are really complex (tracing JIT technology, etc...)

Comment: If your loop code is long enough that it matters how long it takes to scan across it, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it depends on the user agent and more specifically, its javascript engine. Modern engines are pretty clever, and may ignore it all together, especially if it can deduce that the branch is dead code and will never be executed. I.e., this code can safely be ignored:

```
if (false) {
  // Do a bunch of stuff
}
```

However even if it didn't, it's very likely you would need pretty massive amounts of code in your branch for it to actually make a difference in parsing latency. A few lines won't make enough of a difference to warrant any speed concerns.

As always when it comes to performance however, measuring is really the only thing that matters. People will say all sorts of different things about what is faster, but that is meaningless without proof, so if you are unsure about which is faster: measure it! You may get very different results depending on the javascript engine, so its best to take this route over asking StackOverflow anyway, even if this *is* a very smart community.

Check out [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) for a nice way of measuring the difference across different user agents.

Comment: Thank you! I will Check out jsperf. Besides, my problem isn't practical but theorical. I have a requestAnimationFrame loop that works ok, but I was wondering if I am doing the right thing. Just that.

Comment: Thing is, when talking about performance, it's almost always useless to be theoretical because you're very likely to end up being wrong. When talking about performance, measuring is really the only thing that matters. Until you've measured, you never know.